# How to have a subject line with spaces in an email link

Tags: html

When I click on this email link, I only get "Some" in the subject. Do I need to escape out of the link to make the space register?

```
<a href="mailto:here@there.com?subject=Some questions">here@there.com</a>
```

Comment: Try an underscore or dash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can substitute spaces with `%20`:

```html
<a href="mailto:here@there.com?subject=Some questions">here@there.com</a>
```

to

```html
<a href="mailto:here@there.com?subject=Some%20questions">here@there.com</a>
```

The `%20` char translates to a single space in the ASCII table, meaning you will get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape your link using the `encodeURI` function in javascript. Just run it in the console of your developer tool of choice and copy the result (it takes care of other unexpectedly invalid characters for you too).

This snippet:

```
encodeURI("mailto:here@there.com?subject=Some questions")
```

returns `"mailto:here@there.com?subject=Some%20questions"`.

Comment: That's also a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in between your words to act as a space `%20`